# passing method reference to be called in script using Serializable object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, types, serializable

I have a Serializable object that I'm trying to store a method to be called. From this object, I would like to define a method from ScriptA to be called in ScriptB from SerializableScript.

The Serializable script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "NewFieldInput", menuName = "Data/New Field Input Scene")]
[System.Serializable]
public class CallInput {
   public (some type) callMethod; // this is the confusing part
}
```

I would then have ScriptA have a method that will be called in ScriptB by referencing the value of callMethod passed into scriptB.

Comment: I am unsure if I understood you correctly but can’t you just store a reference to ScriptA in ScriptB and a public method in scriptA which takes your parameter? Alternatively you could use Events

Comment: I'm using scriptable objects to define a connection that is dynamic based on the state of the game. This scriptable object will have a continuous conversation. As a set point in the conversation, it will trigger an int that will then prompt a text field. As the script getting the data could be any script not just ScriptA but what ever script is defined in the scriptable object I can't simply reference scriptA directly. The game has many scriptable objects and they will not all be pointing to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions to your problem and it depends on the rest of your structure what would be the best to use.

1. [UnityEvent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent_1.html) where you create an event and add your target methods as listeners. In all other cases I would use C# events or actions instead but UnityEvents can be subscribed in editor.
2. You could create a base class that implements all the methods you want to call and inherit all your classes from that.
3. Basically the same but you create an [Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface) and add that to all classes you are calling.

It comes down to whether you want to only call your own code which you can modify or external code too. If the latter is the case you should go with option 1.
There are many more ways to do this but these came to mind first.